# A beginner needs help in revising this

Tags: c

I am writing a calculator and it has an option that allows users to use it again. Y/N only. I have this function already but it only reads 1 character. Thus, it accepts n89 as yes.

```
char getSingleCharInput() {
    char input;
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    return input;
}
```

How can I edit this so even for example 'n89' is not read as no? only 'n', 'N', 'y', or 'Y' would be accepted?

I am a beginner with C.

Comment: an essential skill of any software engineer is to engage into a cycle of thinking --> writing code --> verifying --> experiment

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I'm afraid this question is missing focus. Please see [ask] in the [help]. There are many code examples related to this already online.

Comment: That's (apparently) a general-purpose function that returns a single `char`.  You probably want it to return an `int` instead, so that it can signal errors and end-of-file, but any way around, it is answering the question "What is the *next* non-whitespace character available from the standard input?", and it is furthermore discarding any subsequent characters (unsafely).  You apparently want to know something about the next *word* that is not conveyed by the next character alone, so this function is simply wrong for the job.  Write a different one.

Comment: Users enter *lines*, not characters. Even if a particular user input is a single character, it is a single character *line*. Always think and operate in terms of lines. You don't need a function that reads a character. Read a line and then check if it contains "y" or "n".

Answer (score 3):

In order to discard invalid input, you must read the input character and check for a newline.

Here is a simple solution using `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// get confirmation from the user
// return EOF at end of file
// otherwise return 'y', 'Y', 'n' or 'N'
int getSingleCharInput(void) {
    for (;;) {
        char input[2];
        char eol[2];
        int res = scanf(" %1[yYnN]%1[\n]", input, eol);
        if (res == EOF)
            return EOF;
        if (res == 2)
            return input[0];
        scanf("%*[^\n]");  // discard any pending characters
        scanf("%*1[\n]");  // discard the pending newline
        printf("invalid input, enter [Y/N]: ");
    }
}
```

Here is an alternative using `fgets()` if there is no pending newline in the input stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// get confirmation from the user
// return EOF at end of file
// otherwise return 'y', 'Y', 'n' or 'N'
int getSingleCharInput(void) {
    for (;;) {
        char buf[80];
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            return EOF;
        if (strspn(buf, "yYnN") == 1 && buf[1] == '\n')
            return buf[0];
        printf("invalid input, enter [Y/N]: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: 2nd code using `fget()` is quit nice.

Comment: instead of `strspn`, one could use `memchr`: `if (memchr("yYnN", buf[0], 4) == 1 && buf[1] == '\n') ...` Probably simpler to understand and more efficient.